# Databinding with MVVM Light and VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm-light

I'm playing around with MVVM Light for integration into a VB.NET project. I've setup a minimal example, but it would not work. The binding seems to go only one direction to the viewmodel but no notifications arrive at the view:

```
<Application x:Class="Application"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:mvvmlight2"
  StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"  
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  d1p1:Ignorable="d" 
  xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">

<Application.Resources>

  <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:mvvmlight2.mvvmlight2.ViewModel"  />

</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The model goes straight forward

```
 Namespace mvvmlight2.ViewModel

 Public Class MainViewModel
  Inherits ViewModelBase

  Public Property Size As Integer

 ....
```

The locator

```
 Namespace mvvmlight2.ViewModel

  Public Class ViewModelLocator

   Public Sub New()
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(Function() SimpleIoc.[Default])
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register(Of MainViewModel)()
   End Sub

   Public ReadOnly Property Main As MainViewModel
    Get
     Return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(Of MainViewModel)
    End Get
   End Property

  End Class

 End Namespace
```

The view

```
 DataContext="{Binding Path=Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
 ... 
 <Label Content="{Binding Size}"  />
 <Slider Value="{Binding Path=Size}" />
```

The slider changes the value in the model as I can see in the debugger. But the labels content won't changed.

What can I do?

TIA

Comment: does your size call OnPropertyChange? by the way MS says "Avoid Databinding to the Label.Content Property"  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613560%28v=vs.100%29.aspx use textblock instead

Answer (score 0):

Your properties must fire the PropertyChanged event, which in MVVMLight, is done via the `RaisePropertyChanged()` functions.  In C#, there are snippets available, which create properties like:

```
/// <summary>
/// The <see cref="SummaryVisible" /> property's name.
/// </summary>
public const string SummaryVisiblePropertyName = "SummaryVisible";

private bool _summaryVisible = false;

/// <summary>
/// Sets and gets the ShowSummary property.
/// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
/// </summary>
public bool SummaryVisible
{
    get
    {
        return _summaryVisible;
    }
     set
    {
        if (_summaryVisible == value)
        {
            return;
        }
         _summaryVisible = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => SummaryVisible);
    }
}
```

I am sure you can translate that directly into VB.

**EDIT**

Having just looked in my version of Visual Studio, if you install the [MVVMLight Toolkit Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee36692d-ed3f-4888-b904-281aaaeac529), you get the VB snippets as well.